# All language supporting PDF Generation using PHP

Tags: php, html2pdf

I want to generate PDF which will have Chinese  and English. Literally it has to be supported in all language.

I am using html2pdf, I tried many options but not working.

This is my code, tried with different fonts. It takes the font but not printing correctly. Printing some spacial characters instead.

```
         $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en', true, 'UTF-8');

        $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('arialunicid0'); //using this line
        // display the full page
        $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

        // convert
        $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
```

Comment: try wkhtmltopdf as well. as another option

Comment: maybe some solutions [posted in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382868/html2pdf-with-tcpdf-not-rendering-chinese-characters-in-final-pdf-document) can help you

Comment: Check This Out https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_055/

Answer (score 0):

you can create other languages page in HTML and then convert that page into pdf

```
$htmlcode = 'http://localhost:8081/kaamtrade/resume.php?userid='.$userid;
$html2pdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents($htmlcode));
```

i use this code in `mpdf` to convert whole resume html page into pdf.
maybe help in your case.